# Python Implementation of Twilio Media Streams with Google Speech-to-Text not Transcribing (Worked in JavaScript)

Tags: python, flask, websocket, twilio, google-cloud-speech

I am working on a project to transcribe phone calls using Twilio Media Streams and Google's Speech-to-Text API. I have a JavaScript implementation that works perfectly, but when I attempt to rewrite the code in Python, the transcription is not happening. The server starts without errors, and I'm receiving POST requests, but I am not receiving any transcriptions.

I followed this [tutorial](https://www.twilio.com/blog/live-transcribing-phone-calls-using-twilio-media-streams-and-google-speech-text?utm_source=youtube&utm_medium=video&utm_campaign=project_saiyan&utm_content=transcribe_calls) and adapted it to Python. Below is the code.

python:

```
from flask import Flask, request, Response
from flask_socketio import SocketIO
from google.cloud import speech_v1p1beta1 as speech

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'your_secret_key_here'
socketio = SocketIO(app)

transcription_request = {
    "config": {
        "encoding": "MULAW",
        "sampleRateHertz": 8000,
        "languageCode": "de-DE",
        "model": "phone_call",
        "useEnhanced": True,
    },
    "interimResults": True,
}

@socketio.on('connect')
def handle_connect():
    print('New Connection Initiated')
    recognizeStream = None

    @socketio.on('message')
    def handle_message(msg):
        event = msg.get('event')
        print(f"Received event: {event}, Message: {msg}")

        if event == 'connected':
            print('A new call has connected.')
            nonlocal recognizeStream
            recognizeStream = speech.SpeechClient().streaming_recognize(transcription_request)
            for data in recognizeStream:
                if data.results and data.results[0].alternatives:
                    transcript = data.results[0].alternatives[0].transcript
                    print(transcript)
                else:
                    print("Unexpected data structure:", data)

        elif event == 'start':
            print('Starting Media Stream', msg.get('streamSid'))

        elif event == 'media':
            payload = msg.get('media').get('payload')
            print("Received Payload:", payload)
            if recognizeStream and not recognizeStream._stream.closed:
                recognizeStream._stream.send(payload)
            else:
                print('Attempt to write to destroyed recognizeStream ignored')

        elif event == 'stop':
            print('Call Has Ended')
            if recognizeStream:
                recognizeStream._stream.close()

@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def root():
    print("request method is:")
    print(request.method)
    if request.method == "POST":
        response = """
            <Response>
              <Start>
                <Stream url="wss://{host}/"/>
              </Start>
              <Say>I will stream the next 60 seconds of audio through your websocket</Say>
              <Pause length="60" />
            </Response>
        """.format(host=request.headers.get('Host'))
        return Response(response, content_type='text/xml')
    else:
        return "Hello World"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Listening at Port 8080")
    socketio.run(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)
```

I also have a working JavaScript version for reference:

```
const WebSocket = require("ws");
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const server = require("http").createServer(app);
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ server });

// Include Google Speech to Text
const speech = require("@google-cloud/speech");
const client = new speech.SpeechClient();

// Configure Transcription Request for German
const request = {
  config: {
    encoding: "MULAW",
    sampleRateHertz: 8000,
    languageCode: "de-DE",
    model: "phone_call",
    useEnhanced: true,
  },
  interimResults: true,
};

// Handle Web Socket Connection
wss.on("connection", function connection(ws) {
  console.log("New Connection Initiated");
  let recognizeStream = null;

  ws.on("message", function incoming(message) {
    const msg = JSON.parse(message);
    switch (msg.event) {
      case "connected":
        console.log(`A new call has connected.`);

        // Create Stream to the Google Speech to Text API
        recognizeStream = client
          .streamingRecognize(request)
          .on("error", console.error)
          .on("data", (data) => {
            console.log(data.results[0].alternatives[0].transcript);
          });
        break;
      case "start":
        console.log(`Starting Media Stream ${msg.streamSid}`);
        break;
      case "media":
        // Check that recognizeStream is not null and not destroyed
        if (recognizeStream && !recognizeStream.destroyed) {
          // Write Media Packets to the recognize stream
          recognizeStream.write(msg.media.payload);
        } else {
          console.warn('Attempt to write to destroyed recognizeStream ignored');
        }
        break;
      case "stop":
        console.log(`Call Has Ended`);
        recognizeStream.destroy();
        break;
    }
  });
});

// Handle HTTP Request
app.get("/", (req, res) => res.send("Hello World"));

app.post("/", (req, res) => {
  res.set("Content-Type", "text/xml");
  res.send(`
    <Response>
      <Start>
        <Stream url="wss://${req.headers.host}/"/>
      </Start>
      <Say>I will stream the next 60 seconds of audio through your websocket</Say>
      <Pause length="60" />
    </Response>
  `);
});

console.log("Listening at Port 8080");
server.listen(8080);


const WebSocket = require("ws");
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const server = require("http").createServer(app);
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ server });

// Include Google Speech to Text
const speech = require("@google-cloud/speech");
const client = new speech.SpeechClient();

// Configure Transcription Request for German
const request = {
  config: {
    encoding: "MULAW",
    sampleRateHertz: 8000,
    languageCode: "de-DE",
    model: "phone_call",
    useEnhanced: true,
  },
  interimResults: true,
};

// Handle Web Socket Connection
wss.on("connection", function connection(ws) {
  console.log("New Connection Initiated");
  let recognizeStream = null;

  ws.on("message", function incoming(message) {
    const msg = JSON.parse(message);
    switch (msg.event) {
      case "connected":
        console.log(`A new call has connected.`);

        // Create Stream to the Google Speech to Text API
        recognizeStream = client
          .streamingRecognize(request)
          .on("error", console.error)
          .on("data", (data) => {
            console.log(data.results[0].alternatives[0].transcript);
          });
        break;
      case "start":
        console.log(`Starting Media Stream ${msg.streamSid}`);
        break;
      case "media":
        // Check that recognizeStream is not null and not destroyed
        if (recognizeStream && !recognizeStream.destroyed) {
          // Write Media Packets to the recognize stream
          recognizeStream.write(msg.media.payload);
        } else {
          console.warn('Attempt to write to destroyed recognizeStream ignored');
        }
        break;
      case "stop":
        console.log(`Call Has Ended`);
        recognizeStream.destroy();
        break;
    }
  });
});

// Handle HTTP Request
app.get("/", (req, res) => res.send("Hello World"));

app.post("/", (req, res) => {
  res.set("Content-Type", "text/xml");
  res.send(`
    <Response>
      <Start>
        <Stream url="wss://${req.headers.host}/"/>
      </Start>
      <Say>I will stream the next 60 seconds of audio through your websocket</Say>
      <Pause length="60" />
    </Response>
  `);
});

console.log("Listening at Port 8080");
server.listen(8080);
```

thanks :)

Comment: Facing a similar issue making a Sanic Python app work with Twilio and the Google streaming speech recognition API. Does your JavaScript code work? If so, how do I run it? Much appreciated. Thanks.